# Count Lat Lon Data Points Lying Between 2 Azimuths

Tags: python, geopandas, count

I need to count the number of points (LAT, LON) from a cvs file that exist inside an arc defined by 2 azimuths.  Ultimately it will need to be iterative where the arc defined by the 2 azimuths rotates a full 360 degrees counting the # of points in each arc. 
I have installed geopandas as a tool box.

Comment: The problem is that GeoPandas use shapely which uses euclidean distances.

Comment: Can you recommend a better library?

Comment: Search for [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/1.10.0/#) with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.basemap.pyproj as pyproj
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
from shapely import geometry
import requests
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

# Data file path
csv_geo_25 = 
csv_geo_50 = 

# Read in data into Pandas dataframe remove NaN values where no weights were collected
# then renindex the dataframe where were NaN's were removed.
df_geo_25 = pd.read_csv(csv_geo_25)
df_geo_25 = df_geo_25.dropna(how='any').reset_index(drop=True)
df_geo_50 = pd.read_csv(csv_geo_50)
df_geo_50 = df_geo_50.dropna(how='any').reset_index(drop=True)

# Setup Proj class initialized for Alabama West, Zone 0102
myFrag = pyproj.Proj(init='EPSG:2760') #      http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2760/, "Alabama West", Zone 0102

# Convert lat lon to easting northings for 2.5 lb TNT
easting_25, northing_25 = myFrag(df_geo_25['LON'].values,     df_geo_25['LAT'].values)
df_25 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Easting', easting_25), ('Northing',     northing_25)]).join(df_geo_25)

# Convert lat lon to easting northings for 5.0 lb TNT
easting_50, northing_50 = myFrag(df_geo_50['LON'].values, df_geo_50['LAT'].values)
df_50 = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Easting', easting_50), ('Northing', northing_50)]).join(df_geo_50)


# Get ground zero to blast lat and lon
gz_lat =  34.59765667
gz_lon = -86.65476833

# Convert ground zero lat and lon to easting and northing
gz_easting, gz_northing = myFrag(gz_lon, gz_lat)

# Subtract ground zero easting and northing from fragment location data
df_25['X'] = df_25['Easting'] - gz_easting
df_25['Y'] = df_25['Northing'] - gz_northing
df_50['X'] = df_50['Easting'] - gz_easting
df_50['Y'] = df_50['Northing'] - gm_northing

# R
df_25['R'] = (df_25['X']**2 + df_25['Y']**2)**0.5
df_50['R'] = (df_50['X']**2 + df_50['Y']**2)**0.5

# Theta
df_25['Angle_Radians'] = np.arctan2(df_25['Y'], df_25['X'])
df_25['Angle_Degrees'] = df_25['Angle_Radians']*(180.0/np.pi)
df_25['Azmuth'] = np.where(df_25['Angle_Degrees']>=0.0,     df_25['Angle_Degrees'], 360.0+df_25['Angle_Degrees'])
df_50['Angle_Radians'] = np.arctan2(df_50['Y'], df_50['X'])
df_50['Angle_Degrees'] = df_50['Angle_Radians']*(180.0/np.pi)
df_50['Azmuth'] = np.where(df_50['Angle_Degrees']>=0.0,  df_50['Angle_Degrees'], 360.0+df_50['Angle_Degrees'])

# Plot fragmen locations and scale point by mass size
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.axes(polar=True)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('E')
ax.scatter(df_25['R'], df_25['Azmuth'], s=df_25['WT_g'])
ax.scatter(df_50['R'], df_50['Azmuth'], s=df_50['WT_g'], color='r')
```